# Extracting website (URL) from Google local search when URL not found in source?

Tags: python, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm looking to extract (with WebDriver, by XPath, CSS Selector, class or id) the URL that lives behind each of the *Website* images in a Google local search results page such as [this](https://www.google.com/ncr#q=chiropractors%2BNew+York,+NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl)

[image]

When I mouseover any of these, I can see the URL that will be reached if I click the image. Yet if I view the full page source and search for any of these URLs, they're not to be found. A look at the source around one of the images:

[image]

suggest that the URLs are perhaps read in dynamically, though this is where my knowledge of web design ends. Is it even possible to construct an XPath or CSS selector or indeed plain-text search for these URLs?

**CLARIFICATION**: When I say URL, I mean the ultimate URLs. Mouseover any of the Website images and you'll see URLs such as *bodinbalanceny.com*, *lamchiropractic.com* etc. – these are the URLs I'm looking to extract.

Comment: Can you provide the URL that you are using

Comment: see the URL in the first sentence

Comment: If you look at the element above the `<div class="_nMg">` there is the href (URL)

Comment: @JamieR When I say URL, I mean the ultimate URLs. Mouseover any of the Website images and you'll see URLs such as *bodinbalanceny.com*, *lamchiropractic.com* etc.

Comment: Sorry, but this is what I am seeing... http://i.imgur.com/9Sm0Bpa.png

Comment: @JamieR That's odd - both Firebug and developer tools are giving me href such as `href="/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBAQgU8wAGoVChMI_ee2oPziyAIVxSYmCh2SBAwg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.taihealthsolutions.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHHoVNRX0zdXZ1Cu4P2xIUEffCZTA&sig2=ky0Q4D6fOicwlkNM-uGWXA&bvm=bv.105841590,d.eWE">` for the exact same `<a>` in which you are seeing the actual URL.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to help you as I cannot reproduce the problem. If you look at your href it contains a `url` parameter, you could extract that out and decode the URL.

Comment: @JamieR OK, thanks for the input, will try that. Upvoted each of your comments.

Comment: @Pyderman - Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use urlparse. Once you fetch the `href` attribute, append "https://www.google.com" to it and then try the code below.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = """https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBAQgU8wAGoVChMI6c6MhpvjyAIVQyeUCh0EIAAi&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.taihealthsolutions.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHHoVNRX0zdXZ1Cu4P2xIUEffCZTA&bvm=bv.105841590,d.dGo"""
>>> parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['url'][0]
http://www.taihealthsolutions.com/
```

**Note:** This is for Python 2.x. For Python 3, the code is different.